# When is macro expansion performed?

Tags: macros, racket

I'm learning about [macros in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html) (language successor of Scheme). There is no mentioning of when the macro expansion is performed. On page 17 of [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/13wi/unit5notes.pdf) document I found a paragraph that says it happens before type-checking, evaluation and compiling.

So if I understand correctly, macro expansion occurs right after building the abstract syntax tree (AST)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although a Racket expert might correct me, my understanding is that the main stages are:

1. A **read pass** that processes the input characters into a syntax object.
2. An **expansion** pass that recursively expands the syntax object, including using user-defined macros.
3. **Evaluation**. (JIT compilation happens during evaluation, whenever a not-yet-compiled function is called.)

In other words the REPL (read eval print loop) is really more like a REEPL (read expand eval print loop).

For an extreme level of detail see [Language Model](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/model.html) including e.g. the [Syntax Model](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html) section.

You mentioned "type-checking".

- Plain Racket (e.g. `#lang racket`) is dynamically typed and checking is done at runtime.
- Typed Racket (e.g. `#lang typed/racket`) does static type-checking during expansion: the Typed Racket system is implemented via macros. See Section 10, "Implementation", of Sam Tobin-Hochstadt's [dissertation](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/dissertation-tobin-hochstadt.pdf).

(Edited to note the JIT is actually part of evaluation, not a separate stage.)